# Is it possible to get a negative reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Is it possible to get a negative total reputation? I can't find any examples where this has happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. From the Help Center article [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to obtain a negative reputation, as proved by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-start-at-1-and-have-a-lower-bound-of-1) question from the Stack Exchange Meta site.